# Getting error in Python: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python

I don't understand my mistake.

```
a = ["capitale paris", "capitale londres", "capitale berlin"]
for k in range(0,4):
  b = a[k+1]
  print(b)
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\PycharmProjects\myfirstproject\quizz.py", line 4, in main
    b = a[k+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the expected output?

Comment: Change it to `b = a[k]` python is zero-based indexing. Also `range(0, 3)` or just `range(3)`

Comment: Your list only has 3 elements in it. Remember, indexes start from 0. `range(0,4)` contains the numbers `0,1,2,3`. On the first iteration, you access the `k+1`th element in `a` where `k=0`. So, you essentially are accessing the item at the first index, i.e., `"capitale londres"`. The next iteration is `1`, `k+1=2`. You access `"capitale berlin"`. Next, `k` is `2` and `2+1=3`. This results in `a[3]`, which does not  exist in your list, hence, *list index out of range*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to access the index k+1 in the list a, this ranges between 1 and 4 since k ranges between 0 and 3.
So if you are trying to print all the elements of a, I would suggest you change b = a[k+1] by b = a[k].
I would also recommend to change the upper bound of the range to len(a) so that your code could be generalized. The following code summarizes all this:

```
a = ["capitale paris", "capitale londres", "capitale berlin"]
for k in range(0,len(a)):
  b = a[k]
  print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["capitale paris", "capitale londres", "capitale berlin"]
for k in range(3):
  print(a[k]) 

//or simply
for k in a: 
  print(k)
```